# Storing password in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

I am considering storing user-entered password in session state. Are there any security risks or issues that I need to be aware?

Comment: read this related post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862096/is-storing-login-and-password-hash-in-session-secure-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is just a really bad idea.  You shouldn't even store passwords in a database - best practice is to store hashes of passwords instead.  So you can validate the password but if somebody gets access to the database (or session state in your case), they don't actually have the user's password.

Comment: But session state is not necessarily in a database, which would make it more secure. Is it OK to store passwords in session state if session state is not persisted?

Comment: passwords should never ever ever be stored anywhere.  salt+hash passwords as soon as they hit the server and then only operate on that result.  you have no need to ever operate on the user's raw password.

Comment: I used to agree with that, but I'm coming to realize that's an idealistic world and I don't know that we live in that world. When a web server has to interact with third party components that don't support token based authentication, a password is the only way in. The site I use for electronic billing asks for my password so that it can get bills from third parties. I suspect that its storing something that might allow someone else to log in to those third parties if they got a hold of that data. I just don't think sites provide the ideal kind of interface you're after.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN you are right that there are some sites that interface with 3rd party services and do need to store passwords.  This is the exact scenario that the OAuth and other protocols were invented for though.  You gotta do what you gotta do for legacy systems but anything new has no excuse to ever store a unhashed/salted password.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net, there are many places where session data can be stored. Most commonly in development, it's InProc, or basically in RAM memory. However you could one day decide to use a different session provider, like a database, or using Windows Azure Cache. **Storing passwords in clear text would make them visible when they are transmitted over the network** in both of these cases.

In the above scenario, with session data traveling over a network, unless the transfer is sent over https, clear passwords would be visible.

Comment: your answer has no relation to question

Comment: @palmsnow Actually, olivehour's answer was on-topic; it was pointing out that putting the passwords in `Session` could result in the password being sent over the wire in cleartext, because you might use an external session storage mechanism at some point. I think it's a good point. +1

Comment: @AndrewBarber thats only true if you don't use a secure channel between your servers which would be pretty dumb thing to do

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks, I think it answers the question too -- "Are there any security risks or issues that I need to be aware?" Have bolded the security risk.

Comment: @RobertLevy have you been to stackoverflow.com? There are a lot of people doing a lot of dumb things. I will update my answer to address HTTPS.

Comment: @RobertLevy Definitely true. In practice, however, there's a high likelihood of that happening.