# SecureString vs Hash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, password-protection

Reading this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862096/is-storing-login-and-password-hash-in-session-secure-net-c-sharp) , I am wondering about the pro/cons of [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) vs hash when storing password in session. Any thoughts?

Comment: asking doesn't hurt... why would anyone ever store a password in session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not store a password in session.
<strike>Period.</strike>

You should only ever store passwords as salted hashes in a database (preferably using bcrypt or scrypt).

Comment: @cdeszaq: No, since he's talking about hashes.

Comment: problem is that I have a specific requirement of creating a wizard when registering a user. End user enter his password (and some other questions ) on step 1, then on 3 other steps he enter more information. I don't want to create this entry in database right after step 1 because these wizard has back button also. All this mean that I need to store password from first page somewhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: @palmsnow: Then you should use a hash, and put that hash directly into your database.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now; I was just wondering about pro/cons of using hash vs SecureString

Comment: There is no point in using a SecureString; a hash is more secure, and simpler too.  (If the attacker can get memory access, he can certainly get DB access, so you have bigger issues to worry about in that case)

Comment: What's the point of SecureString. Any string stored as SecureString is not secure?

Comment: @palmsnow: Using SecureString  prevents attackers from seeing your string in memory dumps.  However, if you don't need to retrieve the original string, you might as well only store a hash, which is more secure.