# Session object doesn't store value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently creating a webpage, and I want to transfer one object that is related to the current visitor of the site, to another page. I chose to do this with the Session item. But there seems to be a problem, I declare it's value on one page like this:

```
Session["CurrentAccount"] = new Account(tb_username.text, tb_password.text);
```

And want to retreive this data on another page like this:

```
Account currAccount = (Account)Session["CurrentAccount"];
```

Whenever I try to do this, a nullreferenceexception occurs. 
The Account class isn't marked as serializable. And both pages are running under the same application.

Edit: I've tried to do the same thing but instead binding a regular string to a session, this didn't work either.

Comment: Are the two pages running under the same application context or virtual directory?

Comment: Is `Account` marked as `Serializable`? You should share your `sessionState` key from the web.config.

Comment: Is  `new Account(tb_username.text, tb_password.text);` a misspelling? It should be  `new Account(tb_username.Text, tb_password.Text);` otherwise your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: How come you are storing the password in the first place and are you storing plain text password in the Session object?

Comment: The code is a misspelling, and yes I'm storing the password as plain text in the session object, but in this project security isn't an issue.

Comment: Odd question, but did you make sure your object actually got instantiated properly and didn't throw an error. IE, can you instantiate it, and then immediately access it?

Comment: OK, I would practice not doing this anyway, once you've authenticated the user, you could use forms authentication to make sure who they are by storing UserName in forms auth ticket or in the session object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862096/is-storing-login-and-password-hash-in-session-secure-net-c-sharp for more info

Comment: i have replicated your situation and it is running fine for me.. i seriously have no idea lol

Answer (score 2):

Serializable only counts for SQL Session. This will raise an exception when putting it into the session.

I had the same issue when directly assigning a session to "new object". Try creating the instance first and then assigning the instance to your session!

Comment: Tried creating the instance first, but that didn't help either. Same error.

Comment: Serializable is also required for ASP StateServer-based sessions as well.  Now that I think of it, "in-memory" is likely the only type of session which doesn't require Serializable.

Comment: Serializable is only required for SQL Server. SessionState server is an in memory process as well but using a shares separate process  to support web farming. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've enabled read/write session.

See this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx

Comment: Where exactly do I change the sessionstate property?

Answer (score -3):

I've figured out what went wrong, apparently you can't store custom objects into a session, with the exact same problem but replacing the Account with a regular string, it does work. Thank you for you help.

TL;DR You apparently can't store objects other than standard ones, in a session.

Comment: so you're saying you can't possibly fill a session with a custom object such as Account ? I know for a fact that that is not true, i have filled many session with custom objects. i replicated your question myself and i didnt get any error.. so i think it has to do something with settings on your end

Comment: You actually can do this. Something is just preventing it from working properly in your environment. Chances are, it's a serialization issue.

Comment: http://blog.felipel.com/2009/08/how-to-enable-session-state-in-asp-net/ check out this blog, maybe its something related to that

Comment: Thank you, for a second there I thought it was impossible so it's definitely some kind of mistake on my side indeed. I'll look into it and i'll let you know what it was if I find out.